# jQuery iFrame Variable from Text File in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, variables, iframe, video-embedding

I am trying embed videos using a set of urls and parameters stored in a text file in Wordpress that change at random on F5 refresh. I am not a coder but I think I am close, but wrong and the example is here:

http://aaaad.com/jquery-forum-post/

I have tried a lot of different approaches but cannot seem to get the parameters passed correctly from the file to display the random video and parameters on refresh in the second video frame. From the link above:

- the first video is an iframe embed command with start and stop parameters and works fine
- the second video is an attempt to use the var of "video" to use as the beginning of the src= values
- at the bottom is a random line from the file that changes correctly using div class on refresh of the page that works like I want the video link to.

Any help to redirect my obviously incorrect approach is appreciated. Here is the code:

`<iframe width="854" height="480"     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ad5pmvJ0zMQ?start=1&end=23" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

```
`<iframe width="854" height="480" src=$video frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div class="video"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>// <
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.get('/wp-content/slap/video.txt', function(data) {
        var video = data.split("@");
        var idx = Math.floor(video.length * Math.random());
        $('.video').html(video[idx]);
    });
});
</script>
```

`
Contents of video.txt

```
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ad5pmvJ0zMQ?start=398&end=418"@
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ad5pmvJ0zMQ?start=39&end=41"@
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ad5pmvJ0zMQ?start=98&end=108"@
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ad5pmvJ0zMQ?start=60&end=67"@
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ad5pmvJ0zMQ?start=7&end=20"
```

Thanks again for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things I've spotted..

1. The .video div never closes, so that might lead to some issues. (Maybe it does in your normal code, but it doesn't in what you posted above.
2. This:

   `var video = data.split("@");
   idx = Math.floor(video.length * Math.random());`

Doesn't seem to do what you want it to. Math.random(), if called without arguments, returns a decimal between 0 and 1. To make it between two numbers, you have to provide a min and a max. In your code, the idx variable is very likely just going to be zero. I think you may want instead `idx = Math.random(0, video.length - 1);`

3. You're setting the HTML of .video to just the URL of the video selected. That doesn't work -- You'd need to populate the iframe source attribute tag with the URL to make this work.. Which now begs the question: why are you doing this in Javascript? Does the random video need to be changed again once the page loads? It seems like you could just do this much more simply with only PHP. You'd read from the text file, randomly choose one of the URLs, and then output the `<iframe src="$source">` on page load instead of via AJAX and Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Greg. You are right about the div close, I missed it when copying and corrected it above.

Comment: 2. As far as the Math.random() it does seem to randomize correctly as is. You can see that on the link above at the bottom where I print out the the current value of the text file on hitting F5 to refresh. I expect that if it randomizes there it would work for adding where I tried to do it as src=video as a part of the iframe if I can figure out he syntax. All I am really trying to do there is take the value retrieved from the file as is and replace $video with that. I that div there just to be able to see what it was doing.

Comment: 3. I expect you probably are right. But, I do need it to refresh again and again each time the page is refreshed. I also have a number of things to add to this page in addition to what is here and I have much of that in jQuery already that I will fold in and hope the learning experience with jQuery will help. Thanks much,

Comment: Understood! I just even wonder if part of your problem is that jQuery / Javascript is firing after page load, and by then the iFrame is already in the page DOM with no source attribute. I just worry that Javascript really isn't the way to go about this. PHP can randomize the source for you as well on each page load, and does it all before the page is even sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I definitely have some learning to do and I expect you are right. I have something close to the code above working on a straight html page now but not WordPress. I do see a good bit on when the jQuery sequence of events issue and need to digest it. I have been exploring the php option you recommended a bit also and I think I see what you mean. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

For the html version that works here is something compliments Jake at jquery forum in a case anyone is interested. (Haven't figured out how to make it work in WordPress yet which is likely due to Greg's answer). Contents of video text are in the original post. Here is the HTML version of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
    <style>
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

    </style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.get('video.txt', function(data) {
        var video = data.split("@");
        var idx = Math.floor(video.length * Math.random());
        console.log(video[idx])
        $("iframe").attr("src",video[idx]);
    });
});
</script></head>
<body>
<iframe width="854" height="480"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div class="video">

</body>
```